# How can I notice exp(x) is actually sympy.exp(x)?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm developing a graph-drawing and calculus-performing calculator app with python + Nest.js. I'm using SymPy to bring calculus features, but there's a serious problem while differentiating.

`derivative.py`:

```py
from latex2sympy2 import latex2sympy, latex2latex
import sympy as smp

def derivative(latex):
  ...
  x = smp.symbols('x', real=True)
  f = latex2sympy(latex)
  dfdx = smp.diff(f, x)
  return smp.latex(dfdx)
```

Everything is working well except `sympy.diff()`; it always returns `0` (e.g. `f = sin(x)` would result in `dfdx = 0`).

I found that since `latex2sympy()` returns a function without a library name, `smp.diff()` doesn't think it's a function from SymPy. When I tested the exact same code on Google Colab, it worked just fine.

```py
f = latex2sympy(latex)
# latex = '$$ \sin x $$'
# f = sin(x)

dfdx = smp.diff(f, x)
# dfdx = 0
```

So I think `smp.diff()` wants `smp.sin(x)`, not `sin(x)`.

Answer (score 5):

You created your `x` symbol with `real=True`, but by default `latex2sympy2` creates its symbols without it. This makes the symbols different so you're differentiating by a symbol not present in the expression, giving 0.

You can either create your symbol without `real=True`, or call

```
latex2sympy2.set_real(True)
```

before calling `latex2sympy` to have it use symbols with `real=True`.

Example:

```
>>> latex2sympy2.set_real(True)
>>> f = latex2sympy2.latex2sympy('$$ \sin x $$')
>>> x = sympy.symbols('x', real=True)
>>> sympy.diff(f, x)
cos(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your latex2sympy not knowing about your locally defined variable `x`, and it creates its own variable, also named `x`.

You are taking the derivative of a different variable `x` (thus, the derivative is zero)

You could for example use the latex string as the entire input, using the variable it defines for itself via

```py
smp.diff(f, f.args[0])
```

The function part itself was always correct, as you can inspect with `type(f.func)`

Comment: `f.args[0]` happens to work in this simple expression. But it won't work with something more complicated like `sin(cos(x))`. Note that sympy allows you to call `symbols` multiple times with the same name and get the same result - the issue here is that the arguments were different as shown in my answer.